# Why are only certain worlds open for settling by the souls?

Tags: the-host

When Wanda is talking to Sunny, she says that only certain worlds are open for settling by the souls.

> “Not that the off-world ships are going to,” I told him, shaking my head. “There are lots of worlds, but only a few, mostly the newer ones, are still open for settling. And I'm sorry, Sunny, but I have to send you far away. The Seekers want to find my friends here, and they'd bring you back if they could, so you could show them the way.”
>   <sub>*The Host*, chapter 55</sub>

But why aren't new souls given the option to go to already-settled worlds? How do they keep all the worlds soul-ified if the souls can't go to worlds that already were taken over?

Comment: I don't think they ever explained that. I always assumed it had to do with resources or compatibility to the host or something... maybe in a sequel?!

Comment: Well, Stephenie has said that she's planning a trilogy... so hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

> How do they keep all the worlds soul-ified if the souls can't go to worlds that already were taken over?

From [The Host wikia](http://thehost.wikia.com/wiki/Souls/Physical), apparently one in five thousand souls is capable of reproduction but reproduction produces on the order of a million souls.  And of course, souls that do not reproduce are mostly immortal.  They do not die of old age.  So when a host body dies, they transfer to a new host.

Presumably the older worlds have enough reproduction occurring that they produce an excess of souls.  That is to say, they are net exporters of souls.  Why send new souls to a world that already has plenty?

Answer (score 1):

### 1 in 10,000 are "Mothers" who birth 1 million souls, leading to a surplus

The souls reproduce by a "Mother" (compared to a queen of many insect species), which is one in every five to ten thousand.

> "We're…a little like your hives of bees, or your ants. Many, many sexless members of the family, and then the queen…"
>
> "Queen?" Wes repeated, looking at me with a strange expression.
>
> "Not like that. But there is only one Mother for every five, ten thousand of my kind. Sometimes less. There is no hard-and-fast-rule."

Each mother gives birth to about a million new souls.

> "The mothers…divide. Every…cell, I guess you could call it, though our structure isn't the same as yours, becomes a new soul. Each new soul has a little of the Mother's memory, a piece of her that remains."
>
> "How many cells?" Doc asked, curious. "How many young?"
>
> I shurgged. "A million or so."

It's later stated that the process of reproduction (and the excruciatingly painful death of the mother as a result) is voluntary, but given that they view it as an altruistic act for the benefit of the species, and that existing souls live for a long time, they almost certainly wind up with a surplus population. Given that, it's very likely that the only place those excess souls can go is to new planets.